# Pycharm is not reformatting code

Tags: python, pycharm

I have heritage code in python with semicolon at the end of each line and mixed tab and spaces indentation.
PyCharm reports it at code inspection and suggest to reformat code. The problem is that when I click "Reformat Code" (which IDE recommends), Pycharm does nothing - code still contains semicolons and mixed indentation.
Why Code Reformat does not work?

Sample code:

```
for i in config.args.include:       
    if i.count(":") == 2:
        path, output, prefix = i.split(":");
    elif i.count(":") == 1:
        path, prefix = i.split(":");
        output = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + ".h";
    else:
        utils.fatal("Incorrect -a paramter tuple specification");
```

Comment: Have you tried to ident the code first? Ctrl + alt + I is the shortcut for windows

Comment: What do you expect to get as an answer here? You own the code, which doesn't work. Why don't you just put in some effort to create the minimal example of code, which breaks the "Reformat Code" feature (if it really does) and report it to PyCharm issue tracker?

Comment: My code works, but PyCharm sees PEP8 coding style violation.

Comment: Indenting code does not removing trailing semicolons.

Comment: Okey, you found that PyCharm's inspection reports about "Trailing semicolon in the statement" and suggests to reformat the file. You do that and it appears that semicolon is not getting removed. Looks like a bug. What do you do when you suspect a bug? You go to the project's [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) search for similar issues already reported. If there is no such issues, you create minimal example to reproduce a problem, describe expected behaviour and submit a ticket. So what is the answer you're looking for here?

Comment: OK, you say It's a bug. I thought that this is something wrong with my settings. Now I understand.

Comment: I say it looks like a bug for me. But anyway the best people to tell you for sure whether it's bug or not are the developers of the program and they are on the issue tracker  :)

Answer (score 1):

Please give the code example.  ; at the end of line is not a python syntax. ; is ignored in workable code. But PyCharm cannot parse for example:

```
print "fdfdf"; for x in [1, 2, 3]: print("dsds")    print "d"
```

Ctrl+Alt+L:

```
print "fdfdf"; for x in [1, 2, 3]: print("dsds")
print "d"
```

But can parse:

```
print "fdfdf"   for x in [1, 2, 3]: print("dsds")    print "d"
```

to

```
print "fdfdf"
for x in [1, 2, 3]: print("dsds")
print "d"
```